# How to get the first two pages of a pdf document using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

How to get the first two pages of a pdf document using PHP?

Thanks!

Don

Comment: Get how? As single-page PDF snippets? Images?

Comment: I have a 10 pages pdf file. I only want to get the first two pages as a new pdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read from PDF files, you will need to install the XPDF package.

When you have XPDF/pdftotext installed, you run the following PHP statement to get the PDF text:

```
$content = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext '.$filename.' -');
```

You can download XPDF from http://foolabs.com/xpdf/